# custom editor template are not setting correctly checkbox values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I created an editor template for Boolean types, my problem it's when model attribute it's not nullable, the default behaviour of the checkbox are modified, for example if themodel value is `true` then the checkbox in the view appears without checked. What am I doing wrong??? this is the code.

```
@model Nullable<bool>

@{
    var listItems = new[]
    {   
        new SelectListItem { Value = "null", Text = "Sin Valor" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "true", Text = "Si" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "false", Text = "No" }
    };  

}

@if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsNullableValueType)
{

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Value, listItems)
}
else
{
    @Html.CheckBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what `ViewData.ModelMetadata.v` that you are using in your checkbox means. Have you tried:

```
@model Nullable<bool>

@{
    var listItems = new[]
    {   
        new SelectListItem { Value = "null", Text = "Sin Valor" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "true", Text = "Si" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "false", Text = "No" }
    };  
}

@if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsNullableValueType)
{
    @Html.DropDownList("", new SelectList(listItems, "Value", "Text", Model))
}
else
{
    @Html.CheckBox("", Model.Value)
}
```

Comment: I modified the question for you could see the my old code. And what's exactly i'm trying to do

Answer (score 0):

This example shows in detail the implementation of boolean templates for a dropdownlist that contains Yes, No and Not Set values and also handles null bool values. Inspired from Darin Dimitrov and Jorge above - Thank you.

Model
Student.cs

```
    [Display(Name = "Present:")]
    [UIHint("YesNo")]
    public bool? IsPresent { get; set; }
```

DisplayTemplates: 
YesNo.cshtml

```
@model Nullable<bool>

@if (Model.HasValue)
{
    if (Model.Value)
        { <text>Yes</text> }
    else
        { <text>No</text> }
}
else
    { <text>Not Set</text> }
```

EditorTemplates:
YesNo.cshtml

```
@model Nullable<bool>

@{
    var listItems = new[]
    {   
        new SelectListItem { Value = "null", Text = "Not Set" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "true", Text = "Yes" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "false", Text = "No" }
    };  
}

@if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsNullableValueType)
{
    @Html.DropDownList("", new SelectList(listItems, "Value", "Text", Model))
}
else
{
    @Html.CheckBox("", Model.Value)
}
```

View:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsPresent )
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsPresent )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsPresent )
    </div>
```